# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/u231382487/public_html/templates/sleek_silver/index.php on line 74

Tags: php

this is line 74

```
$thumbnailUrl = $entry->medx-MoBiLeroup->thumbnail[0]->url;
```

why do i keep getting this error ?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an `>`

```
$entry->medx-MoBiLeroup->thumbnail[0]->url; //medx-MoBiLeroup
```

should be

```
$entry->medx->MoBiLeroup->thumbnail[0]->url; //medx->MoBiLeroup
```